# How do I create an object from a string

Tags: c#

I have this object set:

```
Object A
Object AA: A
Object BB: A
Object CC: A
```

how do i create an object of type AA Given a string variable with "AA" in it?  I've been looking at the Activator stuff but can't quite figure it out.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean. A short but complete example of the types involved and what you mean by "this object set" would really help.

Comment: Those are _classes_, not objects.

Comment: I want to create an object of class type BB given the string "BB"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to get the `Type` instance for `AA`, then pass it to `Activator.CreateInstance`.

```
Type myType = typeof(SomeTypeInProject).Assembly.GetType(typeName);

object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
```

Comment: Or `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` for the assembly that the line of code appears within (avoiding the need to specify a type). (Assuming the `AA`, `BB` and `CC` are in the same assembly as the one that's doing the instantiation.)

Comment: so in my example to create an object of class BB given the string "BB": Type myType = typeof(A).Assembly.GetType("BB"); - is that right?

Comment: @Charles: Yes (assuming that they're in the same assembly)