# Creating an instance from a class defined by a string

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

In a namespace I have an arbitrary number of classes fulfilling an interface IModel. Given the name of a class as a string, I want to instantiate that class and store the resulting object in a variable of type IModel.

As I have no experience in reflection, I did not figure out how to do it.

Comment: ... or of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398147/how-do-i-create-an-instance-from-a-string-that-provides-the-class-name?lq=1) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518383/how-do-i-create-an-object-from-a-string?lq=1) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648160/how-do-i-create-an-instance-from-a-string-in-c?lq=1) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493490/converting-a-string-to-a-class-name?lq=1) ...

Comment: This question has been asked over and over. If a site suggests to check whether a question has already been asked before, **please do so**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need reflection here - use [Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Activator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
IModel model = (IModel)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(typeName));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.activator.createinstance).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. I do the following:

```
Type t = Type.GetType("<name of class>");
IModel m = (IModel)Activator.CreateInstance(t); // assuming constructor has no parameters
```